# recursive function : filtering large multidimensional array by key element to HTML list

Tags: php, recursion

I have a multidimensional array as a result from a webservice called from PHP. I cannot edit the webservice, but the result is as

```
array (size=5)
  'id' => int 0
  'name' => 
    array (size=7)
      'it' => string 'Tutti' (length=5)
      'ca' => string 'Tots' (length=4)
      'es' => string 'Todos' (length=5)
      'de' => string 'Alle' (length=4)
      'fr' => string 'Tous' (length=4)
      'nl' => string 'Alle' (length=4)
      'en' => string 'All' (length=3)
  'tree' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'languages' => 
    array (size=7)
  'subTypes' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => int 1
          'name' => 
            array (size=29)
              ...
          'tree' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'languages' => 
            array (size=29)
              ...
          'subTypes' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      1 => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => int 2
          'name' => 
            array (size=29)
              ...
          'tree' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'languages' => 
            array (size=29)
             ...
          'subTypes' => 
            array (size=6)
              ...
```

As you can see, you can interpret it as a multidimensional array of objects. Each objects can have child objects of same type.

My goal is to get **only** the elements on a specific language, fe `en` (and thus rest is not taken). I thought to use a recursive function.

```
// filter array
function getByKey($array, $search, $level, $valuesUsed) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($array[$key])) {
            $valuesUsed = getByKey($array[$key], $search, $level + 1, $valuesUsed);
        } else if ($key === $search) {
            if(!in_array($value, $valuesUsed)) {
                echo "<li> $key = $value </li>";
                $valuesUsed[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    return $valuesUsed;
}
```

Then I call the above function from my HTML template by

```
<div id="foo">
    <?php
        getByKey($routeTypes, 'en', 0, array());
    ?>
</div>
```

`$routeTypes` is the array, obtained from the webservice.
It works as expected, it results as the list here below, which I can wrap with a js library.

```
<ul>
   <li>this is level1</li>
   <li>this is level1</li>
   <li>
       <ul>
           <li>this is level 2</li>
           <li>this is level 2</li>
           <li>
               ... level++
           </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Now, I'm questioning myself if this can be improved ? It doesn't take long to have a list from a large multidimensional array. (a simple `print_r` command resulted in 45000+ characters).

Especially checking the `$valuesUsed` array, to prevent duplicates (yes the webservice has objects which contains child keys which is similar to level - 2 parent (or on other level ...... ))

Each time I am running through the lower levels, I am looping through the `$valuesUsed` array. Is there not a better way to loop through the sublevels ? Maybe an [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) or [`array_walk_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) with a callback function ?

Comment: Is this complete code ? It's seems to be missing some part ? Does it work on it's own ? Are you here for a review or something else ?

Comment: yes, i'm here for a review. Just asking if the recursive function can be improved. The above function will be called in the HTML template. (it displays the list of which i want on the webpage). Edited my post.

Comment: I was asking to come up with a title. The title of your question should describe what your code do!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a (key => value) pair recursively with this function:

```
function array_value_recursive($key, array $arr){
    $val = array();
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k) use($key, &$val){
        if($k == $key) array_push($val, $v);
    });
    return count($val) > 1 ? $val : array_pop($val);
}
```

This function makes use of [array_walk_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to push into a placeholder array whatever value is pointed to by whichever key matches our needle key.

Proof code:

```
$array = array(
    'id' => 0,
    'name' => array(
        'it' => 'Tutti',
        'ca' => 'Tots',
        'es' => 'Todos', 
        'de' => 'Alle' ,
        'fr' => 'Tous',
        'nl' => 'Alle',
        'en' => 'All'
    ),
    'languages' => array(
        "d" => 33
    ),
    'subTypes' => array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => array(
                'it' => 'Tutti',
                'ca' => 'Tots',
                'es' => 'Todos', 
                'de' => 'Alle' ,
                'fr' => 'Tous',
                'nl' => 'Alle',
                'en' => 'All'
            )
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => array(
                'it' => 'Tutti',
                'ca' => 'Tots',
                'es' => 'Todos', 
                'de' => 'Alle' ,
                'fr' => 'Tous',
                'nl' => 'Alle',
                'en' => 'All'
            )
        ),
        2 => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => array(
                'it' => 'Tutti',
                'ca' => 'Tots',
                'es' => 'Todos', 
                'de' => 'Alle' ,
                'fr' => 'Tous',
                'nl' => 'Alle',
                'en' => 'All'
            )
        )
    )
);

print_r(array_value_recursive("de", $array));
```

The above test code, which seeks all "de" keys, will output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Alle 
    [1] => Alle 
    [2] => Alle 
    [3] => Alle
)
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but yours code didn't kept the child level of the main array. The goal is to get a nested list (menu - submenu) as mentioned in my post.